# Will an app running in Windows 8.1's Assigned Access mode receive automatic app updates?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store, windows-store-app

I'm having a hard time finding any documentation on how automatic app updates interact with accounts using assigned access on machines that aren't domain joined.

If I have an app in the Windows Store and an account configured to run that app using assigned access, and later update the app in the store, will the app ever automatically update for the assigned access user if they've opted in to automatic app updates?

If not, is there a way to update the app for the assigned access user that doesn't involve switching accounts and disabling the assigned access configuration??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsoft's [Best practices for selecting an app for assigned access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn465334.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) :

> Updating a Windows Store app can sometimes change the Application User
>   Model ID (AUMID) of the app. If this happens, you must update the
>   assigned access settings to launch the updated app, because assigned
>   access uses the AUMID to determine which app to launch.

The answer to your question is that this depends on the update itself.
Which probably means that only quite major app version updates will break the
assigned access.
I imagine that such updates would be relatively rare in the app's lifetime,
but not impossible, and no way to predict such breaks in advance.

Comment: My question is less "will assigned access continue to work?" and more "will the app update without user intervention?"

In my scenario, an app will be running in assigned access mode 24x7 under a user account with automatic app updates configured. Will that app ever actually have an opportunity to update (during reboots or otherwise?)

Comment: After thinking this through, it doesn't really matter. Assuming the app could automatically update, the next problem is that it wouldn't reliably launch under assigned access. Thanks for the insight!